# Aumentar la resolución de una gráfica exportada en Spyder

Tags: python

tengo un código escrito en Python el cual genera una grafica y la puedo visualizar de manera correcta en Spyder. Mi problema suge cuando quiero exportarla a JPG ya que la imagen sale con algo de baja calidad. Mi pregunta es ¿existe alguna manera para que Spyder exporte las graficas en una mayor resolución? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig("nombre_imagen.png")
```

además la función `savefig()`admite el argumento `dpi` el cual puedes modificar para intentar hacer que tu gráfica se vea mejor

Comment: Muchas gracias. Para el caso de la el tamaño de la imagen he usado esto ``plt.savefig('nombre_image.png', dpi=1000.0, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5)`` y ha funcionado de maravilla.